# SMIL SVG animations as a symbol/def/sprite in Firefox

Tags: firefox, svg, svg-animate, smil

In Firefox SMIL animations only seem to work on inline SVG, not when used as a symbol. Chrome seems to support the use when used as both a symbol and inline.

Is this expected behaviour or a bug?

It would be really nice to have the use of them in a symbol so that they can be used in sprites/icon usage.

JSFiddle demoing the difference: http://jsfiddle.net/tuL02p8f/1/

```
<svg class="loading-icon"><use xlink:href="#loading"/></svg>
```

Comment: Its a known bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=738574

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson - here's hoping for a fix soon :) maybe IE will support one day too... :)